# Не выполняется скрипт через CRON

Tags: php, cron

Приветствую читающих вопрос.
Столкнулся с задачей - запускать свой php скрипт через CRON.
Логер вхождений в данный скрипт работает и создает файлик о том,что был запуск скрипта,но остальная часть скрипта не работает. Прописал полные пути от хостинга к либе и всему остальному - все равно ничего. С браузерной строки скрипт успешно запускается и делает то,что мне надо.

```
<?php
require '/home/admin/web/bot.mint-plantation.ru/public_html/parser.php';
$fd = fopen("/home/admin/web/bot.mint-plantation.ru/public_html/arizonam.txt","a"); 
fwrite($fd, "Обращение к файлу - ".date("d.m.Y H:i")."\r\n"); 
fclose($fd); 

$array = array();
for ($i=1; $i <= 1; $i++) { 
    $serverarray = array();
    for($m = 1; $m <= 2; $m++) {
        array_push($serverarray,array($m => getMembers($i,$m)));
        sleep(0.5);
    }
    array_push($array,$serverarray);
}

$f = fopen("/home/admin/web/bot.mint-plantation.ru/public_html/arizonam.json", 'w');
fwrite($f,json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
fclose($f);
```

В чем может быть проблема?
upd:
Решил включить логирование и увидел:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /home/admin/web/bot.mint-plantation.ru/public_html/parser.php:48
Stack trace:

Соответственно встает новый вопрос - как через крон запускать еще либу curl?

Comment: Пишите в поддержку хостинга. Там не включен или не установлен curl

Comment: возможно прав не хаватет..

Comment: у меня вдс-ка и все либы стоят.

Comment: консоль и вэб-сервер обычно юзают разные конфиги пхп. Если вы уверены, что курл сам по себе установлен и при этом еще работает при запуске через вэб, значит он отключен в консольном конфиге.

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо в подсказке @teran https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran

На самом деле проблема оказалась в том,что интерпретатор запускался в стоковом режиме без настроек,соответственно либа не подгружалась.
Решение оказалось такое,что нужно применять настройки при запуске:

```
/usr/bin/php -c /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini -f /home/admin/web/bo.mint-plantation.ru/public_html/lala.php >> /home/admin/web/bo.mint-plantation.ru/public_html/m.log
```